# Jenkins deploy to K8s how to intgerate ? (Kubernetes Continuous Deploy plugin)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, devops

How to integrate Jenkins deploy to Kubernetes ?
I have a plugin Kubernetes Continuous Deploy.
But I have a error. ERROR: ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kubernetes config files are not specified.
I don't know what need to past on Kubeconfig file ?

[image]

Comment: The repository for your plugin seems to mention something about this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin/issues/18

Comment: I readed that tred but I really don't understand which solution. Do you know ?